# React dispatch state not updating in the same method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, dispatch

I have a dispatch updating the state correctly when i was in this scenario with 2 methods ( onClick )

```
const sizesMeasureChoise = useSelector(getSizesMeasureChoise);


  const chooseMeasure = (measure) => {
    dispatch(setSizeMeasureChoise(measure));

  };

  const chooseType = (type) => {
    const sizeChoise = sizesMeasureChoise.description;
  }
```

Then i have changed and i have put everything in one method ( because i have removed the chooseType step ) and the state is not updated after the dispatch

```
const sizesMeasureChoise = useSelector(getSizesMeasureChoise);

  const chooseMeasure = (measure) => {
    dispatch(setSizeMeasureChoise(measure));
    const sizeChoise = sizesMeasureChoise.description;
    }
```

From what is depending, how can i resolve it?

Comment: The `useSelector` has already captured the original value from the hook, at the time of the render. Attempting to access that right after `dispatch...` won't return the new value.

Comment: Exactly, do you have any suggestion on how i can work around that? Thanks

Comment: If I may ask, what do you do with `sizeChoise` ? I haven't experienced this situation before hence the question. Usually, I have to `dispatch` & then have to access `useSelector` in another component & therefore don't run into the stale closure issue.

Comment: Yes, i have to trim it and then doing some replacing of the value, but i need to update this state in this method before

Answer (score 2):

Once an action has been dispatched, updated values from the store will become available only on the next render.

This behavior is the same for both functional components with hooks as well as with classes that use the connect HOC.

You'll just have to modify your code so as not to expect changes immediately.

If you could describe what you want to get (rather than "how") with a minimal sample with only the relevant hooks & how data is rendered then it will be
easier to suggest a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation, i have put minimal code to not overwhelm the question with irrelevant code, my scenario is clear and i think i give inputs for a detailed answer or at least put me in the right direction. An answer without code can not be accepted, but thanks for the explanation